# Fastest way to find, fetch and replace part of the string in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a set of records in database table and one of the columns has string value. Something like  `HeyHelloWorld1` or `HeyGoodDayWorld2` or `HeyHowdyWorld32`. I need to change them all to `GoodEveningWorld` (and whatever comes at the end of the string). I'm trying to run script but it takes too long and I was wondering if anyone knows of a fastest way to implement this

The script:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $str_to_look_for = 'Hey';
 $new_str = 'GoodEvening';
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE item LIKE '%$str%'");
 if(!$result) echo "No records found?";
  else
    {
  echo " Found ".mysqli_num_rows($result)." rows<br/>... Executing script...";
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
          $val = strstr($row['item'], '/World');
          $new_val = $new_str.$val;
          $id = $row['ID'];
          insert($new_val, $id, $con);
        }
        echo " DONE!";
    }


  function insert($x, $id, $con)
      {
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table1 SET item = '$x' WHERE ID = '$id'");
    if (!$result) echo "missed..<br/>";
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [MySQL String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) and consider replacing it directly in the database.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET item = 
  CONCAT(
    'GoodEvening',
    SUBSTRING( item, INSTR( item, 'World') ) 
  )
```

This would work for anything followed by World, rather  than just HelloWorld or HayWorld.

Comment: It worked as a charm! A second instead of two minutes!! Amazing! Thanks Andresch!

Comment: @user3065540 you're welcome. Consider accepting my answer so this question get's marked as answered thus doesn't get any more unneeded attention.